# How to use FakeItEasy to assert a method was not called

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit, fakeiteasy

I want to assert that **nothing was dispatched**, a.k.a. **`_dispatcher.Dispatch` was not called**.

`interface` being faked/mocked:

```
interface IDispatcher
{
    void Dispatch<T>(T command, 
                     Stuff stuff = null,
                     TimeSpan? timeout = null,
                     int? retries = null) where T : Command;
}
```

In the test body:

```
_dispatcher = A.Fake<IDispatcher>();

// do stuff

A.CallTo(() => _dispatcher.Dispatch(A<Command>.Ignored,
                                    A<Stuff>.Ignored,
                                    A<TimeSpan?>.Ignored,
                                    A<int?>.Ignored)).MustNotHaveHappened();
```

This **test passes** when **something was dispatched**.

Any ideas? Am I using FakeItEasy incorrectly?

Comment: You're most probably setting up the wrong CallTo(). For example: are you sure that you want to have A<AuthorizationHeader>._ and not A<Stuff>._ as second parameter?

Comment: Have you tried it the other way round? Does .MustHaveHappened() work when something is dispatched? I would guess not.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually making a call to `Dispatch<T>`? Also, `DispatchWork` and `Dispatch<T>` are two different methods.

Comment: @D.R. Updated the question. That was a typo.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Updated the question -- typo.

Comment: @Scoobie Why don't you post the code in the `//do stuff` section? Your current code looks fine to me.

Comment: Please use MustHaveHappened() and see what actually is dispatched.

Answer (score 3):

@Scoobie

Is the actual type, that you call the dispatch method with, really `Command`? Or is it a derived type? If it's a derived type that would probably lead to the behavior you observed.

See the following example:
    var dispatcher = A.Fake();

```
dispatcher.Dispatch(new Command(), new Stuff());

A.CallTo(() => dispatcher.Dispatch(A<Command>.Ignored,
                                    A<Stuff>.Ignored,
                                    A<TimeSpan?>.Ignored,
                                    A<int?>.Ignored)).MustNotHaveHappened();
```

This test will fail, as expected.

But if you have something like this:

```
public class NewCommand : Command
{
}
```

The following test

```
var dispatcher = A.Fake<IDispatcher>();

dispatcher.Dispatch(new NewCommand(), new Stuff());

A.CallTo(() => dispatcher.Dispatch(A<Command>.Ignored,
                                    A<Stuff>.Ignored,
                                    A<TimeSpan?>.Ignored,
                                    A<int?>.Ignored)).MustNotHaveHappened();
```

Will succeed, though you expected it to fail.

But this is how FakeItEasy works. If you like to discuss if it should work this way head over to https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy and open an issue, please.

Now for your issue. I assume you want to ensure that the `IDispatcher.Dispatch` method is never called, no matter which type the generic argument has.
You have a couple of options:

As the `Dispatch` method is the only one on the `IDispatcher` I would just write the following

```
A.CallTo(dispatcher).MustNotHaveHappened();
```

This fails when any method (or property) on the `dispatcher` instance is called.

```
A.CallTo(dispatcher).Where(_ => _.Method.Name == "Dispatch")
    .MustNotHaveHappened();
```

This only fails when a call to `Dispatch` is made, though this usage is a refactoring killer.

I would prefer the first alternative if possible in your case.